# Convert a MySql query into Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT* FROM cubes LEFT JOIN xkvs ON cubes.id=xkvs.cube_id WHERE xkvs.cube_id IS NULL
```

I tried the method from the laravel documentation but always get an error, that `xkvs.cubes_id` is an unknown column.

How do I write this correctly?

This is my try:

```
$cubes=DB::table('cubes')
        ->leftjoin('xkvs', function ($join) {
            $join->on('cubes.id', '=', 'xkvs.cubes_id')
                 ->where('xkvs.cubes_id', '=', null);
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: Can you try https://bpaste.net/show/9aa8b948eae2 ? I am posting this as a comment since I've never used laravel, nor eloquent in my life yet. Just a wild guess from the docs.

Comment: thanks for helping, but this did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DB::table('cubes')
    ->select('cubes.*')
    ->leftjoin('xkvs', 'cubes.id', '=', 'xkvs.cubes_id')
    ->whereNull('xkvs.cube_id')
    ->get();
```